# TempData in MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having a TempData variable which has the array of values. How can I access the value or convert the TempData array into array int.

I have tried below code. but its not working.

```
string[] allowRenew = (string[])TempData["ServiceID"];
foreach (var data in TempData["ServiceID"] as List<int>)
{
    serviceIDList.Add(data.ToString());
}

for (int i = 0; (object[])TempData["ServiceID"].Count; i++)
```

Please help me out. How can I get the values using for or foreach loop.

Comment: int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll(allowRenew , int.Parse);

Comment: where is TempData? How can TempData be  converted ??

Comment: Your code: string[] allowRenew = (string[])TempData["ServiceID"]; is fine. It will convert it to string array.

Comment: You actually do not need a foreach loop to get the data and convert them to a list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string array to integer array:

```
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll(allowRenew , int.Parse);
```

then you can loop the integer array.

```
for(int i=0;i<intArray.Length-1;i++)
{
}
```

Comment: I only want to get access array of TempData["ServiceID"]

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your tempdata holds only integers then use

```
int[] temp = (int[])TempData["ServiceID"];
```

In case of null values in array

```
int?[] temp = Array.ConvertAll(TempData["ServiceID"], TryParseInt32);
```

Comment: I am getting error.       {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Int32[]'."}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution you are looking for:

```
int[] temp = (int[])TempData["ServiceID"];
```

**Note**:

`TempData` whose underlying type (`TempDataDictionary`) implements `IDictionary<string, object>`:

```
public class TempDataDictionary : IDictionary<string, object>
```

Accessing the dictionary by key returns object - so , you can cast to the required type.

Answer (score -1):

1) Make your array or collection with datas and assign it to TempData["ServiceID"] in Controller's Action Method.
2) In the view make your foreach iterate

```
foreach (var data in TempData["ServiceID"] as type of array/collectin assigned in the controler)  
{  
    //do want you want with the data
}
```

Comment: Not true, and doesn't answer the question.